# Is there was way to get the leftmost column in a Google visualization table to stay fixed while side-scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-visualization

I'd looking to emulate the standard google visualization table header row behavior, but have it apply to the first column.  This doesn't seem to be a built-in feature, but I'm wondering if it can be accomplished with some custom CSS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up reverse engineering how google was accomplishing the top header.  They were creating a copy of the entire table, putting it in a div, absolutely positioning it and setting a height equal to the height of the first row.  That accomplishes the effect that when you scroll down the main table it stays fixed at the top.

Side-scrolling is more complicated, because when side-scrolling they need the header to also scroll.  CSS doesn't have a mechanism for this (since it's absolutely positioned outside of what's scrolling), so Google's using javascript here.

To emulate this behavior for a fixed column, we first make a third clone of the table.  Then we go through some CSS gymnastics to get the width/height & position correct.  Finally, we attach a listener to the onScroll event of the main table that scrolls the header table in unison.  The $.schollbarWidth() function comes from [this plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-misc-plugins/#scrollbarwidth).

```
visualization = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table'));
visualization.draw(data);

var fullTable = $('#table > div > div:first');
var yHeader = fullTable.clone().insertAfter(fullTable);
yHeader.css('width', yHeader.children('tr td:first').outerWidth())
       .css('height', fullTable.innerHeight() - $.scrollbarWidth())
       .css('position', 'absolute')
       .css('top', '0px')
       .css('left', '0px')
       .css('overflow', 'hidden')

fullTable.scroll(function() {
  yHeader.scrollTop(fullTable.scrollTop());
});
```

Comment: I can't get this to work.  Could you provide this example within the context of a webpage?  I just get the table duplicated underneath.  Should fullTable be a div or a table element?

Comment: I did it this way also. Though more in depth.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using .children() I used .find() and now it is OK. Also, to make it working after column has been sorted, we have to add an event listener and run the whole code again. Here is an exemplary code:

```
table.draw(data_summary_table, {allowHtml : true, width : '880'});    

function frozenColumn() {   
var fullTable = $('#summary_table > div > div:first');
var yHeader = fullTable.clone().insertAfter(fullTable);
yHeader.css('width', yHeader.find("tr td:first-child").outerWidth())
       .css('height', fullTable.innerHeight() - $.scrollbarWidth())
       .css('position', 'absolute')
       .css('top', '0px')
       .css('left', '0px')
       .css('overflow', 'hidden')

fullTable.scroll(function() {
  yHeader.scrollTop(fullTable.scrollTop());
}); 

}

frozenColumn();

google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'sort',
      function(event) {
frozenColumn();
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases the browser gives an error like "$.scrollbarWidth is not a function". Just change it to property. $.scrollbarWidth.

```
table.draw(data_summary_table, {allowHtml : true, width : '880'});    

function frozenColumn() { 

    var fullTable = $('#summary_table > div > div:first');
    var yHeader = fullTable.clone().insertAfter(fullTable);
    yHeader.css('width', yHeader.find("tr td:first-child").outerWidth())
        .css('height', fullTable.innerHeight() - $.scrollbarWidth)
        .css('position', 'absolute')
        .css('top', '0px')
        .css('left', '0px')
        .css('overflow', 'hidden')

        fullTable.scroll(function() {
        yHeader.scrollTop(fullTable.scrollTop());
        }); 


}
```

// Attached the event

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'ready', frozenColumn);
google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'page', frozenColumn);
google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'sort', frozenColumn);
```